# Change the column name according to the query date (month)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting the commission for sales person every month. I need to make the column name changes according to the month I run the query in.

like when i run the query in 30/1/2016   then the coumn name is `commission for month 1` or `commission for month January`

like when i run the query in 30/3/2016   then the coumn name is `commission for month 3` or `commission for month March`

I tried this code :

```
Select T0.commission as 'Commission for month month(getdate())'
```

it doesnt work

Comment: I think you'll have to do that dynamically. Personally I don't like constructions like this, but I assume you're stuck with this setup...

Comment: Any given query will always generate a result set with a fixed shape - the number, *names* and types of the columns. Do you not have a better place to deal with presentation logic like this (e.g. a reporting front-end or an application)?

Comment: Also, imagine how confusing it would be to program in SQL Server if it actually did this "if a string happens to contain something that looks like an expression, evaluate the expression and replace it with the value so obtained".

Answer (score 3):

This query will return some dummy data (table names out of a system view. The column will be named with a dynamically generated string:

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)='SELECT TABLE_NAME AS [' + 'placeYourColHere_' + CAST(MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(10)) + '] FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;';
EXEC(@cmd);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this query

```
select 'Commission for month ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(2),DATEPART(MM,GETDATE())) AS 'Date'
```

Comment: Nice idea, worth an upvote... But we don't know how many rows the OP's query will return and to repeat this over and over might not be the solution...

Comment: but your code works properly, mine is just returning as column data not as column